# Let $m$ and $n$ be two integers. Prove that $mn+m$ is odd if and only if $m$ is odd and $n$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

---The statement:
Let $m$ and $n$ be two integers. Prove that $mn+m$ is odd if and only if $m$ is *odd* and $n$ is *even*.

---Solution:
First, we show that if $m$ is *odd* and $n$ is *even*, then $mn+m$ is *odd*. Assume that $m$ is *odd* and $n$ is *even*. Then $m = 2a+1$ and $n = 2b$ for integers $a$ and $b$. So $mn+m = (2a+1)(2b)+(2a+1)= 4ab +2b+2a+1=2(2ab+b+a)+1$. Since $2ab+b+a$ is an integer, $mn+m$ is *odd*.
Next, we verify the converse, that is, if $mn + m$ is *odd*, then $m$ is *odd* and $n$ is *even*. Assume that it is not the case that $m$ is *odd* and $n$ is *even*. Then either $m$ is *even* or $n$ is *odd*. Therefore, either $m$ is *even* or $m$ and $n$ are both *odd*. We consider these two cases.
Case 1. $m$ is *even*.
Case 2. $m$ and $n$ are both *odd*.

---My question:
Why didn't we consider a third case where $m$ is *even* and $n$ is odd

Comment: The solution for Case1 doesn't care if n is even or odd, so it includes both.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question, but this fact can be proved much more succinctly if you use modular arithmetic, assuming of course that you're familiar with it. Suppose $m\equiv 1\mod2$ and $n\equiv 0\mod2$, then $mn + m \equiv 1\mod 2$ follows immediately. Conversely if $mn+m\equiv 1\mod2$ then $m(n+1)\equiv 1\mod2$ which implies that $m$ and $n+1$ are both odd, and therefore $m$ is odd and $n$ is even.

Comment: mmh I think you should consider it

Comment: Keep it simple: $nm + m = m(n+1)$ is odd iff $m$ and $n+1$ (the factors) are odd, that is iff $m$ is odd and $n$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$mn+m=m(n+1)$ is odd iff both factors $m$ and $n+1$ are odd iff $m$ is odd and $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly just an aesthetic choice how you split this into cases. As you suggested handling the cases

- m even and n odd
- m even and n even
- m odd and n odd

Is perfectly acceptable. You're basically just enumerating the possible parity of each pair of m and n. If you do this you will probably realize that you don't even need to consider the value of n for the 1st two cases. So instead it's a good idea to consider only the state of m

- m is even
- m is odd (this forces n to also be odd)

Answer (score 0):

$mn+m$ is even $\iff$ $m$ is even $\lor$ $n$ is odd.

Therefore if and only if $m$ is odd $\land$ $n$ is even, is $mn+m$ odd.